# UPDATE: Dynamic MultipleChoiceField changes instances to strings

Tags: python, django, post, modelchoicefield

I have a django form that has a multiple choice field. The field should be dynamic, that is,  only the records associated with the user who is currently logged in should be displayed. I've managed to put this together so far;

forms.py

```
class myForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, someUser, *args, **kwargs):
        super(myForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        someRecords = models.SomeModel.objects.filter(someUser = someUser)
        #The line above gets records associated with a specific user

        displayNames = []
        for i in someRecords:
            displayNames.append((i.someField, i.someOtherField + ' ' + i.someOtherField2))
            #I am basically making a list of tuples, containing a field and a concatnation of two other fields. The latter will be what is displayed in the select box

        self.fields['theSelectField'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices = displayNames)

        class Meta:
            #I defined model, fields and labels here
```

views.py

```
def myFormPage(request):
    someUser = request.user.someextensionofuser.someUser
    form = forms.myForm(someUser)
    context = {'form': form}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = forms.myForm(someUser, data = request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            #Do Stuff if form is valid. However,this stuff doesn't get done, the page refreshes instead
```

So I've managed to make the select options dynamic. However, now I can't submit data.

EDIT: One of the comments helped me solve the previously stated problem. I've updated the views.py code. However, now I'm running into this error;

> Cannot assign "'someString'": "someModel.someField" must be a
> "someForeignModel" instance

The option values seem to be strings instead of references to objects. How do I solve this?

Comment: Since you override the constructor of the form, you should clearly write `myForm(someuser, data=request.post)` so Django will know it is not your first argument `someUser`

Answer (score 0):

This limits the possible options of your select field:

```
self.fields['theSelectField'].queryset = SomeModel.objects.filter(someUser = someUser)
```

In your views you might want to use a Class Based View, because it handles a lot of stuff automatically and saves you time. Take a look here: https://ccbv.co.uk/

Comment: I appreciate that. However, I want to customize how the options are displayed, that's why I didn't go with that solution in the first place. Notice my "displayNames" array

Answer (score 0):

I firgured it out. Since my main problem was with how the options are displayed to a user, I decided to go with changing my **str** method in models.py to;

```
class someModel(models.Model):
    #my fields

    def __str__(self):
        return self.someField + ' ' + self.someOtherField
```

Then in my forms.py, I went with @dmoe's answer;

```
self.fields['theSelectField'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset = models.SomeModel.objects.filter(someUser = someUser))
```

So now both problems are solved. My options have custom labels, and I can submit my data without running into valueError.